# Android: Divide one String into 2 String values from responseBody

Tags: android

With this function I got a String from the server as a response:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

the String value I retrieve looks more or less like this:

```
"http://url.com 765889"
```

I want to divide the URL and the numbers into 2 String values, it should be:

```
String 1="http://url.com" 
String 2="765889"
```

How am I able to perform that?

Comment: try  StringTokenzier with " " as separator

Comment: Please note that [`StringTokenizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is considered legacy - new code should be using [`split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
String 1 = responseBody.substring(0,responseBody.indexOf(" ")-1);
String 2 = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf(" ").responseBody.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function:

```
String[] parts = responseBody.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples do this

```
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer("http://url.com 765889"," ");
    Log.d("first", t.nextToken());
    Log.d("second", t.nextToken());
```